# Navigation issue in html pages

Tags: html, css

I had problem to load the li in nested navigation. Here is the problem suppose i'm having a five elements(li) in the parent ul. If i click on any element(li), I can see 30 child elements(ul li) in list. Now the problem is how do I have assign them in three rows?
Below is the structure. I have tried like splitting the them into rows but no use.

```
ul(parent)
li
li
li>ul(child)
li   li(1)        li(11)       li(21)  
li   li (2)       li(12)      li(22)
     .. (3)       ..       ..
     ..        ..       ..
    (10th li) (20th li)(30th li)
```

Comment: What CSS did you use?

Comment: normal css like taking parent group(ul and li) in one class and child group in another class

Comment: You could make your child `ul` a specific width so it fits 3 `li`s next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

I am not following you question 100% but it sounds like you are trying to nest more than one level deep? If you are ..

Simple just nest some more ul elements within the li tags.

```
<ul>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>
   3
   <ul>
     <li>3.1
       <ul>
         <li>3.1.1</li>
         <li>3.2.1</li>
       </ul>
     </li>
     <li>3.2
       <ul>
         <li>3.2.1</li>
         <li>3.2.2</li>
       </ul>
     </li>
     <li>3.3
       <ul>
         <li>3.3.2</li>
         <li></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   <li>4</li>
   <li>5</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. it is not matching my requirement.Like is said for one parent li it has 30 child li and they have show in 3 rows(each contains 10 li list

Answer (score 0):

[**SEE THE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4gmjJ/1/). Is this what you want? Basically, you will have to define the width for the second `ul` and float your `li`. Your code should be like:

```
ul.primary {
position: relative;
}

ul ul { 
width: 400px;
position: absolute;
top:0; left: 0;
}

ul ul li {
float: left;
}
```

Comment: If you want that to happen on click, you can use jQuery and assign the click event.